# SSLStream.BeginRead and IOCP

Tags: c#, networking

Just like socket Begin\End methods use IOCP, would that also be true for SSLStream Begin\End Read\Write  methods

if not how do you get a tcp\ip server on SSL to scale 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SslStream` presumably is wrapped around a regular `SocketStream` I would say this is highly likely, because at some point the async `SslStream` is going to have to perform a read on the underlying stream. It is only logical that it would implement this in terms of an async read on the underlying stream.

Having said that I cannot give you a 100% certain answer, but unless you are prepared to go with an SSL library or 'implement your own', even if it didn't, would that deter you from using the `SslStream`?

Comment: no youre right I have to use SSL so this was more like a "someone reassure me please that I will get IOCP scalability :-) "